# asignar valor a un dropdown generado dinámicamente en un ng-repeat (ANGULAR.JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy tratando de recrear un problema real, asi que puede parecer raro este ejemplo, pero de seguro resolverá mi problema.
Agradecería mucho si me pueden ayudar.

tengo un botón, que al hacer click sobre él, genera 3 dropdowns dinámicos( se alimenta una variable llamada $scope.dropdown, con la lista de los animales que contiene el array $scope.aAnimals, actualmente existen 3 elementos, pero en un futuro pueden ser "n" elementos).

Despues de esto, quiero que cada dropdown tenga un valor diferente, por ejemplo, que el primer dropdown tenga el primer animal, el segundo dropdown el segundo, el tercer dropdown el siguiente.
He intentado muchas cosas, pero no he podido lograrlo.

```
<div ng-repeat='item in dropdown'>
 <select class="form-control animal" ng-model='MyAnimals' id='animal{{$index}}' name='animal{{$index}}'  
ng-options="opt as opt.animal for opt in aAnimals  track by opt.animal">
      <option style="display:none" value="">Select an animal</option>
 </select>
</div>
<button ng-click='add()' >generate</button>


$scope.obj = {}
$scope.aAnimals=
[
 { "animal": "cat"},  //first dropdown
 { "animal": "dog"},  //second dropdown
 { "animal": "parrot"}  //third dropdown
]


$scope.add=function(){
$scope.dropdown=[];
for(var i in $scope.aAnimals){
 $scope.dropdown.push({ "animal": $scope.aAnimals[i].animal })
 //$('.animal')[i].value=$scope.aAnimals[i].animal;
 }
}
```

Cuando se generen los dropdown deberia tener algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 { "animal": "cat"},  //first dropdown
 { "animal": "dog"},  //second dropdown
 { "animal": "parrot"}  //third dropdown
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JF1PBblo6VGKdeWvoqTz?p=preview

Comment: Siempre cada select tendrá una sola opción?, "solo un animal"?

Comment: @wZVanG cada dropdown deberia contener un valor diferente, asi como la imagen http://i.imgur.com/gmiGamn.jpg

Comment: @wZVanG ya te entendi, todos los animales siguen apareciendo en todos los dropdowns. lo importante es obtener el resultado de la imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta declarar una variable `$scope.MyAnimals` para que tengas una referencia en cada select a qué animal pertenece dependiendo la posición.

```
$scope.MyAnimals = [];
$scope.add=function(){
   $scope.dropdown=[];
   for(var i in $scope.aAnimals){
     $scope.dropdown.push({ "animal": $scope.aAnimals[i].animal });
     $scope.MyAnimals[i] = $scope.aAnimals[i]; //El modelo de cada Select
    //$('.animal')[i].value=$scope.aAnimals[i].animal;
   }
}
```

Y en el HTML, tenemos que identificar el modelo a cada select con `ng-model`. Cada modelo está categorizado por posición de cada dropdown  con la ayuda de la variable incremental `$index`.

```
<div ng-repeat='item in dropdown track by $index'>
     <select class="form-control animal" ng-model='MyAnimals[$index]'  
    ng-options="opt as opt.animal for opt in aAnimals">
       <option value="">Select an animal</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: tengo otra pregunta respecto la respuesta que me diste, puedes ayudarme? será facil para ti y te agradeceria http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44641/eliminar-dropdown-din%C3%A1mico-siempre-se-elimina-el-%C3%BAltimo